# Jsf page cannot call bean's method

Tags: jsf-2, el, managed-bean

I have this very simple page wich is driving me crazy.
basically I have 2 buttons calling method on a bean, but it won't call them, each time I get :

javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /vues/vehicule/creationVehicule.xhtml @49,94 action="#{creationVehicule.creer}": Method not found: fr.efrei.gpa.web.beans.vehicule.ModificationVehiculeBean@1387498.creer()

this is my controller (I removed the imports)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ManagedBean(name = "creationVehicule")
@ViewScoped
public class CreationVehiculeBean implements Serializable{
    //
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4790600937909196533L;
    private String immatriculation;
    private Date dateAchat;
    private String marque;
    private String modele;
    private String kilometrage;
    private String puissance;
    private String etat;

    private VehiculeService vehiculeService = new VehiculeDelegate();

    public void creer() throws Exception{
        Vehicule v = new Vehicule();
        v.setImmatriculation(immatriculation);
        v.setKilometrage(kilometrage);
        v.setMarque(marque);
        v.setModele(modele);
        v.setPuissance(puissance);
        v.setEtat("etat");
        v.setDateAchat(dateAchat);
        int id = vehiculeService.create(v);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/web-office/vue/vehicule/rechercherContrat.xhtml&id="+Integer.toString(id));
    }

    public String annuler(){
        return "/vues/vehicule/rechercheVehicule?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

And this is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:cogepat="http://cogepat.com/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ccc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/compositeForms"
    xmlns:cccg="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/compositeGeneral">

<ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="module" value="vehicules" />
    <ui:define name="title">
        #{msg.CreerUnProduit}
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="titreModule">
        #{msg.GestionVehicule}
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="onglets">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="tab" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/vues/vehicule/rechercheVehicule.xhtml">#{msg.RechercherUnVehicule}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="selectedTab" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/vues/vehicule/creationVehicule.xhtml">#{msg.CreerUnVehicule}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="nav">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink id="link1" value="#{msg.vehicules}" action="rechercheVehicule.xhtml" />
                >#{msg.creation}
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>


    <ui:define name="titreOnglet">
        #{msg.FormCreationVehicule}
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpsContenu">
        <ccc:formVehicule bean="#{creationVehicule}" />
        <div class="boutons">
                <h:commandButton type="submit" value="#{msg.creer}" action="#{creationVehicule.creer}" />
                <h:commandButton type="submit" value="#{msg.annuler}" action="#{creationVehicule.annuler}" />
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

so when I clic on either one of those buttons I get the error.
which is weird because I'm calling method in other bean from other page in the excat same way.

[image: the buttons]

Any ideas?
thanks.

I'm using the JDK 6u35, 
richfaces 4.2.1.Final, 
tomcat 7, 
and JSF 2.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look once again at the exception message and then particularly at the class name:

```
fr.efrei.gpa.web.beans.vehicule.ModificationVehiculeBean@1387498.creer()
```

That's not the FQN of the `CreationVehiculeBean` class which you're having at hands. This suggests that you've another managed bean class `ModificationVehiculeBean` which uses exactly the same managed bean name and got precedence in classloading and/or was the last one in managed bean registration.

Giving the `ModificationVehiculeBean` class a different managed bean name should fix this problem.

Comment: oh god, copyNpaste error. you are a god.
But in my defense it has been 13h since I started :p.
thanks a lot =D.